# Need a query for many to many relationship in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Below is the table structure:

I have three tables : employee, skill and employee_skills.

```
Employee: id, firstname, lastname, etc.....
Skill : id, title, description 
Emplyoee_skills : id, employee_id (FK of employee table), skill_id(FK of skill table)
```

---

Now, I want the below output:

---

```
Employee
Id    firstname    lastname
1     Rajnikant    Patel
2     Steve        Jobs
3     Sachin       Tendulkar
4     Ratan        Tata
```

---

```
Skill
Id    title        description
1     java         java
2     mongodb      mongodb
3     PHP          PHP
4     spring       Spring framework
```

---

```
Employee_skills
Id    employee_id   skill_id
1     1             1
2     1             2
3     2             1
4     3             2
```

---

So I want the query which can return the employee records who have the skills that are passed:

Let's say, I pass in where clause : **s.title in ('mongodb', 'java')**, then it should return record:

```
Id   firstName        lastName
 1   Rajnikant        Patel
```

Because this employee has both the skills.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill) > 2?

Comment: That skill array may be flexible.

Comment: How will this skill array be entered?

Comment: That will be coming from java side. User can enter as many skill titles as he wants from search form.

Comment: why don't you use `WHERE s.title = 'mongodb' and s.title = 'java'` instead of `IN` clause

Comment: @Gaurav Lad: Because `IN` translates to `WHERE s.title = 'mongodb' OR s.title = 'java'`, not `AND`. And `IN` is more readable. You condition is plain wrong: A column in a record cannot have two different values at the same time obviously, so your condition can never be true.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: you said the condition is plain wrong, but looking to your example it looks correct, if we observe for 'mongodb' and 'java' you have id 1,2 in Skill table, and in 3rd table you will get Employee.id as 1 for both the records, so here `WHERE s.title = 'mongo' and s.title = 'java' satisfies the condition

Comment: @GauravLad, one row can't have both values at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it: Select all employee skills for the desired skills, then only keep employees having the full count.

```
select *
from employee
where id in
(
  select employee_id 
  from employee_skills
  where skill_id in
  (
    select id 
    from skill
    where title in ('java', 'mongodb')
  )
  group by employee_id 
  having count(distinct skill_id) = 2
);
```

When adding another skill, you must check for a count of 3, of course, etc.

Comment: will you be having 2 parameters in any case for your IN clause like ('mongodb', 'java') as i can see you are applying `HAVING count (distinct skill_id = 2`

Comment: @Gaurav Lad: As mentioned, when I change the number of skills I must adjust that number. Either you build the complete query dynamically anyhow or, yes, you'd pass two parameters, the array and its count.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Not working, it's returning all the records.

Comment: No, it works just fine. See the SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5a88/1. There must be something wrong with your data or you changed the query somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you desired results.

```
SELECT e.id, e.firstname, e.lastname
FROM Employee e
JOIN Employee_skills es
ON es.employee_id = e.id
JOIN Skill s
ON es.skill_id = s.id
WHERE s.title IN ('mongodb', 'java')
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING count(s.id) = 2
```

Comment: The `IN` clause will give result for either 'mongodb' or 'java' as well.

Comment: This makes no sense. Show me a record where the title is 'mongodb' and 'java' at the same time. It simply isn't possible.

Comment: @Samier:  if we observe for 'mongodb' and 'java' you have id 1,2 in Skill table, and in 3rd table you will get Employee.id as 1 for both the records, so here `WHERE s.title = 'mongo' and s.title = 'java' satisfies the condition

Comment: Have rectified the query in my post. The count value 2 will have to be changed according to the number of skills required.